# Difference of convex functions over a convex function

Tags: analysis

If $f(x)$ is a decreasing and convex in $x$, $f(x)>0$, $x\geq 0$, and
$$g(x)=\frac{f(x+y)-f(x+z)}{f(x)}$$ for any $z\geq y \geq 0$. Can we make some assumptions or add some constraints to $f(x)$ so that $g(x)$ is decreasing in $x$?

Comment: Are you assuming $f>0$? Otherwise as $x$ approaches a zero of $f$ from the left, $g(x)\to +\infty$.

Comment: Yes, thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 2):

It's not true.  For example, suppose $f(x) = 1+\epsilon - x$ on the interval $[0, 1]$ with $y = \epsilon$, $z = 2\epsilon$, and $0 < \epsilon < 1/2$.
Then $g(0) = \frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}$ while $g(1-2\epsilon) = 1/3$, and $g(0) < g(1-2\epsilon)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you think it's possible to make an assumption about $f$ that would be sufficient for the statement to hold? For example, suppose $f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda(x)}$ for some $\lambda>0$, $g(x)$ would be constant in $x$. Without give $f$ a specific form, can we add some constraints/assumptions to it so $g(x)$ is decreasing in $x$?